# How to list contents of matched directories whether or not Get-ChildItem string input contains wildcards or not in PowerShelll

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to consistently list directory contents in the following scenario i.e.

```
$dirs = @("C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir[3-5]")

foreach ($d in $dirs) {
  Get-ChildItem $d
}
```

For the first and second iterations the directory contents get listed, but for the 3rd iteration only the matching directories get listed rather than their contents.

Please provide for PowerShell v2+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Get-Item` to perform the wildcard expansion and then get the child items of each match:

```
foreach ($dir in Get-Item $dirs) {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note:

- [Don Cruickshank's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173179/45375) provides an effective and elegant solution.
- This answer provides some **background information** and offers an alternative solution based on `Convert-Path`.

---

Indeed, **a directory path specified as a [*wildcard* expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) causes the matching directories *themselves* rather than their *content* to be listed**:

Literal path:

```
# NO wildcard -> directory *content* is listed
PS> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows

    Directory: C:\Windows


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
d-----        4/11/2018   7:38 PM                addins                                                                                                        
d-----        8/16/2018  10:06 AM                appcompat                                                                                                     
d-----        10/9/2018   5:39 PM                apppatch
```

Wildcard path (note the `[...]` around `s`):

```
# Wildcard -> resolved directory *itself* is listed
PS> Get-ChildItem C:\Window[s]


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
d-----        9/18/2018  10:07 PM                Windows
```

Therefore, **in order to list directories' *contents*, wildcard expressions must be *resolved to their matching paths*, *before* passing them to `Get-ChildItem`.**

One option is to use the [`Convert-Path` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) first<sup>[1]</sup>, and pass its output to `Get-ChildItem` via the `-LiteralPath` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ('C:/dir1', 'C:/dir2' + (Convert-Path 'C:/dir[3-5]'))
```

<sup>Note: Using `-LiteralPath` isn't strictly needed, but good practice, because specifying paths *positionally* - as the first positional argument - implicitly binds to the `-Path` parameter, which interprets its arguments as *wildcard patterns*, and there is a risk of literal paths accidentally *looking like* wildcard patterns.</sup>

Note how the above command passes all (resulting) directories as an *array* to a *single* invocation of `Get-ChildItem` which makes the command more efficient.

However, in a given scenario you may still need to use individual `Get-ChildItem` calls in a loop:

```
foreach ($dir in 'C:/dir1', 'C:/dir2' + (Convert-Path 'C:/dir[3-5]')) {
   Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir
}
```

<sup>Note the use of `+` - array concatenation, in this case - to ensure that a *flat* array of paths is created; by contrast, `'C:/dir1', 'C:/dir2', (Convert-Path 'C:/dir[3-5])` would create a *nested* array, with the wildcard-resolved paths all stored in a sub-array stored in the output array's last element.

Given that `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath` also accepts *arrays*, this wouldn't cause an error, but it wouldn't result in *one-by-one* dir. processing.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] There's also a [`Resolve-Path` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Resolve-Path), but it returns `[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo`] instances, which aren't strictly needed here, since it is *strings* that bind to `-LiteralPath`.

Also, `Convert-Path` always returns an actual *filesystem* path, whereas `Resolve-Path` resolves to *PS drive*-based paths, if applicable - while that won't make a difference here, it would if you passed the paths to .NET methods, for instance.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $d` instead of `Get-ChildItem $d` since the first pipline variable will be used as the `-Path` which allows wildcard expressions. `-LiteralPath $d` does not.

```
$dirs = @("C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir[3-5]")

foreach ($d in $dirs) {
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $d
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating. Just to spell it out for future readers: Your solution will look for a directory _literally_ named `C:/dir[3-5]`.

Comment: Just to clarify - I want to allow wildcards. If a wildcard path is found, I want to list all contents in all matching directories.